# 401 error on jsdebug file when changing WCF service to use an interface

Tags: wcf, windows-authentication, webforms

Scenario. I add an "AJAX-enabled WCF Service" to my ASP.NET application (webforms). This results in the following (long namespaces truncated):

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MyService
{
    // To use HTTP GET, add [WebGet] attribute. (Default ResponseFormat is WebMessageFormat.Json)
    // To create an operation that returns XML,
    //     add [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)],
    //     and include the following line in the operation body:
    //         WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
    [OperationContract]
    public void DoWork()
    {
        // Add your operation implementation here
        return;
    }

    // Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]
}
```

I change 
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")] 
to 
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://domain.com/services")]

To my page I add:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference path="~/Services/MyService.svc" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

I also add a javascript function so I can call the service:

function callDoWork(){
  domain.com.services.MyService.DoWork();
}

The website is run with Windows authentication. When I run the page, the jsdebug file is generated, found, and domain.com.services.MyService.DoWork(); works with no problem. This is confirmed with FireBug. So my next step is to create an interface and have the service class implement it. So now I have:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://domain.com/services")]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();
}
```

and

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        public void DoWork()
        {
            // Add your operation implementation here
            return;
        }
    }

and change the web.config to say contract="Namespace.IMyService"

Now, I get a 401 error on the jsdebug file. Anyone ever seen this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This was a red herring. For whatever reason, also having a mex endpoint on the service caused this to occur. I take the mex endpoint off, and the 401 goes away. Not that this is a solution, but at least I get past my error.